# No. of occurrences of maximum item in a list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a `list`

```
L= [3 2 1 3 5 4 5 3 5 3]
```

Output should be `3` as `5` is maximum in the list as its no. of occurrences is `3`

I am able to try this till now

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in height:
    d[i] += 1
result = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print len(result)
```

But this is not working for every list as it is only giving maximum occurrences of a item in a list but sometimes it is not maximum item.

Comment: So what have you tried so far and where is the problem?

Comment: What about finding the max object first and then counting its occurrences?

Comment: If it's a list, should be as simple as coupling `max` with `list.count` ...

Comment: That's not a list, that's a syntax error.

Comment: Why are you calling `len` on your key-value pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `max` and `list.count`:

```
max_element= max(L)
count= L.count(max_element)
print(count)
```

Comment: This can be slower than the OP's approach and you didn't quite touch upon why the the OP's approach failed (it was only *slightly* wrong).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, I know. I wasn't planning on posting an answer at all, but since nobody had posted the most obvious solution to the problem, I stepped up to get some free rep _*insert evil laugh*_. But to be fair, I don't think there was a need to explain why OP's code didn't work. OP himself said _"this is not working for every list as it is only giving maximum occurrences of a item"_.

Comment: Of course there is a need to explain; they are trying to figure out why it doesn't work. Don't just give the OP a fish, teach him how you caught it and why they didn't.

Answer (score 3):

You were picking the maximum *count*, rather than the maximum *item*. You could have solved this by dropping the `key` argument to `max()`, and then just print the result (not the length of it, that'll *always* be 2!):

```
result = max(d.iteritems())
print result  # prints the (maxvalue, count) pair.
```

Alternatively, print `result[1]` to just print the count for the maximum value.

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#itertools.Counter) to count your items, then find the maximum key-value pair in that:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(L)
max_key, max_key_count = max(counts.iteritems())
print max_key_count
```

Like your own, this is a O(KN) approach where K is the length of `L` and `N` is the number of unique items. This is slightly more efficient than the `max_element = max(L); count = L.count(max_element)` approach in that it avoids looping over all of `L` twice. Which one is faster in practice depends on how much smaller `N` is to `K`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Code:-

```
L= [3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3]
newDict = {}
for i in L:
   newDict.setdefault(i,0)
   newDict[i]+=1

 filter( lambda x : (newDict[x] == max(newDict.values())) ,newDict)[0]
```

Comment: There is no need to call `.keys()`; iterate over `newDict` directly.

Comment: And why drop the use of `collections.defaultdict`? You don't explain where the OP went wrong either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yest it is, Thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters yet i didn't checked collections

Answer (score 0):

you can use **numpy** as a short solution

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([1,3,3,3,1,3,4,5])
x = np.bincount(l).argmax()
print(x)
```

result => 3